# MIPS recursion gone wrong

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, mips

So, i'm having trouble translating my C code to mips. The task is to write a mips code for recursive function that sums up even numbers, and returns integer. I believe my C code is correct:

```
int sumRec(int arr[], int len){
    if(len==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(arr[len]%2==0){
        return arr[len]+sumRec(arr,len-1);
    }
    else{
        return 0+sumRec(arr,len-1);
    }
}
```

But, when it comes to translating it into MIPS, I have great difficulties. I think that logically it is well written, but I can't figure out why I have so much errors on my output (exceptions of 4 and 7 types). This is my code:

```
    .data
      test:             .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
      length:           .word 5
      x:                .word 0
      y:                .word 2
      summ:             .asciiz "summ: "
      nl:               .asciiz "\n"

    .text

    main:
      #prints "summ: "
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, summ
      syscall


      #calling sumRec
      la $a0, test          
      la $t0, length
      lw $a1, 0($t0)
      jal sumRec    

      #print output
      move $a0, $v0
      li $v0, 1
      syscall

      #exit
      li $v0, 10
      syscall


    sumRec:
        addi    $sp,    $sp,    -12
        addi    $t1,    $t0,    -1        #compute len-1
        lw      $t6,    y
        sw      $t1,    0($sp)            #save len-1 in stack
        sw      $ra,    4($sp)            #save return address
        bne     $t1,    $zero,  else_01
        li      $v0,    0                 #set return to 0
        addi    $sp,    $sp,    12
        jr      $ra

    else_01:
        li      $t7,    4                 #t7 = 4
        mult    $t1,    $t7               #len-1 * 4
        mflo    $t2
        add     $t2,    $t2,    $a1
        lw      $t3,    0($t2)
        div     $t2,    $t6
        mfhi    $t4
        beq     $t4,    $zero,  else_02
        sw      $t3,    8($sp)
        move    $a1,    $t0
        jal     sumaRec
        lw      $t3,    8($sp)
        add     $v0,    $v0,    $t3
        lw      $ra,    4($sp)
        addi    $sp,    $sp,    12
        jr      $ra

    else_02:
        move    $a1,    $t1
        jal     sumaRec
        lw      $ra,    4($sp)
        addi    $sp,    $sp,    12
        jr      $ra
```

Could anybody please help me figuring it out? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The last element of the array is `arr[len-1]`, not `arr[len]`.

```
int sumRec(int arr[], int len){
    if(len==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(arr[len-1]%2==0){
        return arr[len-1]+sumRec(arr,len-1);
    }
    else{
        return 0+sumRec(arr,len-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's weird, but they are working just the same, yours and mine version. Do you think I have a problem with my MIPS because of that?

Comment: @NemanjaZoric There's a problem with your MIPS code then.  The similar behavior is actually expected given your inputs because `arr[5]` ends up pointing to the `length:` label.  This causes you to sum over the array `{2,3,4,5,5}` instead of `{1,2,3,4,5}`, but there's no effect because the extra `5` and ignored `1` do not contribute to the sum.  If you change your `1` to a `2`, or decrease the size of the array (making the length an even `4`) you'll get different behavior.